# How to grep 2 same strings on lines after eachother

Tags: grep, lines

I want to find out if there are lines in a text that are similar and after eachother. For example I want to find if there are any lines that has "cccc" in and after eacother.

```
aaaaaaaa
bbbbaaaa
ccccxxxx
ddddaaaa
eeeeaaaa
ccccxxxx   <---
ccccyyyy   <---
ddddaaaa
eeeeaaaa
```

So I should print out only the double cccc**** lines.
I tried something like:

```
 grep "cccc" -A1 file.txt
```

but got all "cccc*" lines.

Simple problem I know...
Another example:
Search for duplicates of "Finland":

```
Iceland
Germany
FinlandsIsNiceButNoMatch
France
FinlandWillMatchTHisTime    <---
FinlandWillAlsoMatch        <---
Hungary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match two lines if they both begin with at least 3 identical letters:

`grep -Pzo "([a-zA-Z]{3}).*\n\1.*" file.txt`

Comment: Check the updated question... How can I match it as a string?

Comment: @Jugglr69 Well that gets trickier! :D Is the duplicate always at the beginning of the line? Could you clarify what you mean by "similar" more precisely? I edited my answer to match two lines that start with the 3 same letters.

Comment: By similar I mean, "Finland1234" and "Finland456" are similar... I was thinking to use my first attempt grep -A1 and get "two line"-groups and see if they match.

Comment: @Jugglr69 Isn't my updated answer what you need? It works on your examples anyway.

Comment: It might work but I get "memory exhausted" with that grep.

Comment: @Jugglr69 What is the size of the file you tested it on?

Comment: It is like 1 GiB. So I found a solution that doesn't use as much memory:  grep "Finland" -A1 testfile.txt | grep -Pzo "([ <a-zA-Z]{10}).*\n\1.*"

I also added space and <, since it was formatted xml in my testfile.
So thank you for your help!!!

Comment: @Jugglr69 Great! You're welcome. I tested my solution on 33Mib, thought it was more than enough.